# Unable to open google doc/spreadsheet/slide links through intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a string from a comma separated google doc/spreadsheet/slide links for example like this "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/136IFK7ZTjjNSy68NZa8D3ymykcQ4_MZBjtDQklMDB6U","https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/195kjpMobg4daj18HW2g5324EFmIf1vHXyaKrOj_DW30"
I am looping through the string and displaying different images based on the link data. On click it should open the link in browser, but instead it throws an exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent 
{ act=android.intent.action.VIEW 
cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT,android.intent.category.BROWSABLE]
dat="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/136IFK7ZTjjNSy68NZa8D3ymykcQ4_MZBjtDQklMDB6U"
}
```

Comment: Please post some code snapshot which is leading to this error

Comment: Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse("googleLinkString));
 browserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
 browserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
 mContext.startActivity(browserIntent);

Comment: Remove `browserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)` and try it again.